# How to replace specified substring with another string for the complete session

Tags: oracle

I want to create a csv file using sqlplus command for multiple tables as below and it will be called inside shell script.

```
sqlplus Username/Password@SSD << EOF
set colsep ,
set pagesize 0
set trimspool on
set linesize 32768
set echo off
spool $TABLE.csv;
SELECT * FROM $TABLE;
spool off;
EXIT;
EOF
```

My Data can also contain a comma(,). if any column data contains comma I want to replace it with "\,".

How can I replace comma for multiple tables and multiple columns? I checked replace function but I don't want to mention column names

Comment: It is not possible without using the replace function on the columns.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are on SQL Plus 12.2 or above, you should be able to get close to your needs with SET MARKUP

```
SQL> create table t ( x varchar2(10), y varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values ('Hello','There');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ('He,llo','The,re');

1 row created.

SQL> set markup csv on
SQL> select * from t;

"X","Y"
"Hello","There"
"He,llo","The,re"

SQL> set markup csv on quote off
SQL> select * from t;

X,Y
Hello,There
He,llo,The,re
```

You don't get the escape, but if you are enclosing things in quotes, then perhaps that won't matter.